# Preventing SQL Injection/Good Ruby method

Tags: ruby, sql-injection

What is a good method in Ruby to prevent SQL Injection?

Comment: Oh any, I'll grab whichever anyone recommends.

Comment: I'm a little surprised at the downvoting, but it may have helped if you mentioned whether you were using a web framework or using plain old ruby objects.

Comment: Yeah, but imo ruby = ruby. So it should imply straight ruby. Also anyone can click on my profile and see if I made other rails questions, which I have not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in straight up ruby? use prepared statements:

```
require 'mysql'
db = Mysql.new('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database')
statement = db.prepare "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ?"
statement.execute 'value'
statement.fetch
statement.close
```

Comment: My problem with this is that it returns an array of results as opposed to a field or something much more manageable.....

Comment: This Is just an example of how to use prepared statements for a select query. What you do with the results is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Not just in Ruby - bind your parameters (be it in the database, or in your client code).

Answer (score 3):

Check out the guide they have up on this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#injection

Basically, you want to use bind variables in your models to find data, rather than inline parameters..

```
Model.find(:first, :conditions => ["login = ? AND password = ?", entered_user_name, entered_password])
```

Comment: Yes, this does look good. Pretty much what I am used to in Java, thanks.

Comment: You should at least mention that you're talking about active record.

Comment: I was just about to comment on this.. in my haste, I forgot to read that it was not specifically for Rails/ActiveRecord.. sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

According to [http://ruby.railstutorial.org/](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-truly_static_pages) you can prevent Cross Site Request Forgery by inserting the

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

tag in the header of app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.

[Direct link of example](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code-application_layout)

Comment: Good idea for those working with web frameworks, but SQL Inejection != XSS

Answer (score 0):

This thread references:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/90258#new

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/82349#143790

ActiveRecord's find() method has built in ways to avoid SQL injection by
using the format

```
 >  :conditions => [ "user_name = ?", user_name]
```

Is there any such system for escaping injection in order?  It seems to
only take a string and feed it to the SQL statement.  This causes a
vulnerability when using params to set : order as in this function:

```
     def list
sort_by = params[:sort_by]
@book_pages, @books = paginate :books,
                               :order => sort_by,
                               :per_page => 10
    end
```

We've tried a few methods to sanitize sort_by such as order => ['?',
sort_by] but it just passes that to the SQL statement like a flattened
array.  The 'escaping magic' does not work for order.  Should I use
gsub! to sanitize params[:sort_by]?